# How to exclude columns from a data.frame and keep the spaces between columns?

Tags: unix, text, space

I have a `tab.table` (like below) with `million` of **rows** and `340` **columns**

```
HanXRQChr00c0001    68062   N    N   N   N   A
HanXRQChr00c0001    68080   N    N   N   N   A
HanXRQChr00c0001    68285   N    N   N   N   A
```

I want to remove `28` *columns*. It is easy to do that, but in the output file I lose the space between my columns.

Is there any way to exclude these columns and still keep the space between them like above?

Comment: Is it a delimited file?  What is the delimiter?  Have you tried `cut`?

Comment: yes, it works with cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try different things. I include some of them below:

```
awk -i inplace '{$0=gensub(/\s*\S+/,"",28)}1' file
```

or

```
sed -i -r 's/(\s+)?\S+//28' file
```

or

```
awk '{$28=""; print $0}' file
```

or using `cut` as mentioned in the comments.